# PHP Connection to SQL Server 20005

Tags: php, sql, sql-server, apache

I have PHP installed on a web server and also have MySQL on the same server and all works perfectly.

I now have SQL Server 2005 installed on another server 192.168.90.250 that I want to connect to as there is a view i want to display in PHP.

I have read around for a number of days but still can not get a connection to work.

I am running on the web server:

- Windows Server 2008 R2
- Apache 2.2
- P 5.3.0

And SQL Server 2005 on another server

I presume I need to download a driver like SQLSRV30 and place the correct .dll file into the C:\Program Files (x86)\PHP\ext directory.

I presume I then need to edit the php.ini file and add something like the following:

```
extension=php_sqlsrv_53_ts.dll
```

I would then need to restart the apache server.

At this point I presume I would be able to use something like the following to connect to SQL Server:

```
<?php
if (function_exists('mssql_connect')) {
    die("Your PHP installation does not have MSSQL support.");
}

$db = mssql_connect ($hostname, $username, $password);

if($db){
    echo "no connection";
}else{
    echo "connected";
}
?>
```

It seems as if I can not run the function `mssql_connect`, as the page just displays a blank page.

If I comment out the:

```
//$db = mssql_connect ($hostname, $username, $password);
```

the page at least displays some data.

I have literally spent days on this, what am I doing wrong?

Am I using the correct driver as there are different versions?

Thanks for your help.

D

Comment: Can anyone help please?

Comment: If you output a `phpinfo()`, is that extension even loaded?

Answer (score 0):

For using the sqlsrv extension you need to use [sqlsrv_](https://www.php.net/sqlsrv) functions or better yet switch to PDO